# Paying with Custom Tokens

Tags: assets, javascript-sdk, payments, trustline, anchor

**UPDATE:  I removed the quotes from BPTOKEN.  That was a mistake.  I had them removed in the real code but cut and pasted a change before this happened.  It has been corrected and the error included.   I also cant figure out how to keep the extras area from printing objects instead of human readable code.**

I am using the JavascriptSDK.  I just set up a Custom Asset with an issuing and distribution account (DISTRO1). I have changed trust and set a limit for the Distribution account using my new BPTOKENS well above 0.   I did not pay the Distribution account any of my new BPTOKENS.  It has a zero balance for my BPTOKENS.

I then set up a secondary Distribution account (DISTRO2).  I changed the trust and set a limit for the DISTRO2 account well above 0.  This time I paid the account 5000000 of my BPTOKENS.

I attempted to set up a payment from DISTRO2 account to DISTRO1 account with the zero balance.  The transaction fails.  Here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');

const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org')
const source = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret('SDDJHVW7TYJMFQ5QKPWQJY2Q5UWJLSC6Y77TVEFCZOHLJEMJKLHUAXQ5')

////////////////
// Keys for accounts to issue and receive the new asset
var issuingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
  .fromSecret('SCWMAYLNIZULNERXQI6DFJ7N4PFCGPX5XY2K33S5OXGHPXWCYA4B2JUT');

// DISTRO2/BASE Account - limit = 5000000
var PayerKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
  .fromSecret('SDDJHVW7TYJMFQ5QKPWQJY2Q5UWJLSC6Y77TVEFCZOHLJEMJKLHUAXQ5');

// DISTRO1/Base Account - limit = 1000000
var ReceiverKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
  .fromSecret('SBKKT7JUQFBWWX5AGA22QCWUXWZRY7PLWFFLKBIR3RE236JDPLHNMUY7');

// Create an object to represent the new asset
var BPTOKEN = new StellarSdk.Asset('BPTOKEN', issuingKeys.publicKey());


var public = source.publicKey();


//////////////

StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork()

server.accounts()
        .accountId(source.publicKey())
        .call()
        .then(
                ({ sequence }) => {
                        const account = new StellarSdk.Account(source.publicKey(), sequence)
                        const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account, { fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE })

                        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment(
                                {
                                        destination: "GADVTLHV5T7J2EZM5MCDBHZMK67Y3H573PCKAOGKE5Y54EEWPFZYWZXB",
                                        asset: BPTOKEN,
                                        // asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
                                        amount: "1.50"  // 1000.50 XLM
                                }
                        ))
                        .setTimeout(30) //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        .build()
                        transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(source.secret()))
                        return server.submitTransaction(transaction)
                }
        )



        .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error!', error);
        });
```

ERROR CODE FOLLOWS:

```
GCXIRXSJSG5HVX3ARXR6A7ZZI6EKQGDEQXKJBSHEVVFXV5RRWZVQSNW6
{ sequence: '2942469209587754' }
Error! { Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/var/www/stellarjs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/var/www/stellarjs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/var/www/stellarjs/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
  config: 
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 60000,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Client-Name': 'js-stellar-sdk',
        'X-Client-Version': '0.15.0',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 367 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
     data: 'tx=AAAAAK6I3kmRunrfYI3j4H85R4ioGGSF1JDI5K1LevYxtmsJAAAAZAAKdCkAAAArAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy0tLUAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAdZrPXs%2Fp0TLOsEMJ8sV7%2BNn7%2FbxKA4yidx3hCWeXOLAAAAAkJQVE9LRU4AAAAAAAAAAACr7YN1HCBOtXX3b7UZEO5tTsQy1Skb0a1tpZGtG1XlAQAAAAAA5OHAAAAAAAAAAAExtmsJAAAAQJDmr9wtDF4fsXer%2By93gu6FBg%2FF5ZRVCP8%2FZqjNCwFpIxybS%2Btr4mPf40KjXuEMWPIpESAOnqmf3h98EGZT5wk%3D' },
  request: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 648,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 32,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0 },
     connection: 
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 648,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 32,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0 },
     _header: 'POST /transactions HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Client-Name: js-stellar-sdk\r\nX-Client-Version: 0.15.0\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 367\r\nHost: horizon-testnet.stellar.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/transactions',
     _ended: true,
     res: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 400,
        statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
        redirects: [],
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable: 
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _ended: true,
        _ending: true,
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 367,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: 
      { accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'x-client-name': [Array],
        'x-client-version': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  response: 
   { status: 400,
     statusText: 'Bad Request',
     headers: 
      { 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0',
        'content-type': 'application/problem+json; charset=utf-8',
        date: 'Mon, 15 Apr 2019 16:43:09 GMT',
        vary: 'Origin',
        'x-ratelimit-limit': '101',
        'x-ratelimit-remaining': '100',
        'x-ratelimit-reset': '1',
        'content-length': '960',
        connection: 'Close' },
     config: 
      { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 60000,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
        data: 'tx=AAAAAK6I3kmRunrfYI3j4H85R4ioGGSF1JDI5K1LevYxtmsJAAAAZAAKdCkAAAArAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy0tLUAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAdZrPXs%2Fp0TLOsEMJ8sV7%2BNn7%2FbxKA4yidx3hCWeXOLAAAAAkJQVE9LRU4AAAAAAAAAAACr7YN1HCBOtXX3b7UZEO5tTsQy1Skb0a1tpZGtG1XlAQAAAAAA5OHAAAAAAAAAAAExtmsJAAAAQJDmr9wtDF4fsXer%2By93gu6FBg%2FF5ZRVCP8%2FZqjNCwFpIxybS%2Btr4mPf40KjXuEMWPIpESAOnqmf3h98EGZT5wk%3D' },
     request: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /transactions HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Client-Name: js-stellar-sdk\r\nX-Client-Version: 0.15.0\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 367\r\nHost: horizon-testnet.stellar.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/transactions',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Object],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Object],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data: 
      { type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed',
        title: 'Transaction Failed',
        status: 400,
        detail: 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html',
        extras: [Object] } } }
```

Question 1:  The documentation on the Stellar website for Issuing Custom Assets payments (https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html), goes through the entire process of changing trust, limits and other steps that seem like initial setup steps vs. a simple payment transaction.  Does a simple payment transaction between two normal or distro accounts need the entire change of trust, limit set and other steps just to exchange assets?

Question 2: If the receiving account has its trust changed to accept BPTOKENS but has a zero balance of said tokens, will the transaction fail if an account with BPTOKENS attempts to send BPTOKENS to the receiving account?

Question 3: Are there other areas that I missed or programming errors I made above?

Comment: Could you add the error code? Would help us narrow it down.

Comment: It sounds like you have several questions. It would be easier to answer if you asked them separately.

Comment: Remove the quotes, you want the asset object not a string in `asset: 'BPTOKEN',`

Comment: Who in the world down voted me for asking a question?  Silly... Anyway, question was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1: Every account that wants to accept/send a given token needs to first create a trustline for that asset once.

Answer 2: There are various possible failures like: asset is auth_required but the account is not authorized;  payment amount exceeds the trust line limit; exceeds senders funds; invalid signatures; invalid trustlines; ...

However you will always get an according error code.

Answer 3)

- The relevant information for transaction failures is hidden in error.response.data.extras, so it would be more helpful to `console.log('Error!', error.response.data.extras);`.
- I've executed the [raw transaction](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAK6I3kmRunrfYI3j4H85R4ioGGSF1JDI5K1LevYxtmsJAAAAZAAKdCkAAAArAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy0tLUAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAdZrPXs%2Fp0TLOsEMJ8sV7%2BNn7%2FbxKA4yidx3hCWeXOLAAAAAkJQVE9LRU4AAAAAAAAAAACr7YN1HCBOtXX3b7UZEO5tTsQy1Skb0a1tpZGtG1XlAQAAAAAA5OHAAAAAAAAAAAExtmsJAAAAQJDmr9wtDF4fsXer%2By93gu6FBg%2FF5ZRVCP8%2FZqjNCwFpIxybS%2Btr4mPf40KjXuEMWPIpESAOnqmf3h98EGZT5wk%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) and it fails with `op_no_trust`, which means that the recipient does not have a trust line for that asset.
- Indeed, the [sender](https://testnet.steexp.com/account/GCXIRXSJSG5HVX3ARXR6A7ZZI6EKQGDEQXKJBSHEVVFXV5RRWZVQSNW6) has a `BPTOKEN` trustline, the payment is a `BPTOKEN` payment, the [recipient](https://testnet.steexp.com/account/GADVTLHV5T7J2EZM5MCDBHZMK67Y3H573PCKAOGKE5Y54EEWPFZYWZXB) does *not* have a `BPTOKEN` but a `BPTOKENS` trustline instead. It's just a typo...

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out last night but this definitely helps with presenting the error in a more readable way.